# how to assign an icon to android custom file type?

Tags: android, icons, customization, file-extension, file-type

in my app i want to open a custom file type, which i have done successfully with the following code in the androidmanifest file. though i declare an icon in the intent filter, android still shows the default file icon along with my file type. how can i change the icon associated with my file type? thank you very much all!

```
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.zd"
                android:scheme="content" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.zd"
                android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:priority="1" >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
            </action>

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.zd"
                android:scheme="file" >
            </data>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:priority="1" >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
            </action>

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="application/my-apps.program" >
            </data>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can assign a file type icon. It is the File browser app´s prerogative to assign icon.